# Is there an equivalent to aws termination handler in azure to deal with spots?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

Is there an equivalent to aws termination handler in azure to deal with spots ? if not what is the best way to relocate resources from spots when notified

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/maksim-paskal/aks-node-termination-handler - it gracefully handle spot termination in AKS, it also can send eviction notification to Prometheus or Slack or Telegram